# Calculator layout not staying stable with varying width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

When i shrink the web page to check for responsive behavior, the layout is all jumbled.

Converted the padding from pixels to rem
Converted font size from pixels to VW

```css
.main-class{
}
.calculator-begin{
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 3.125rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.125rem;
}

.row{
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.screen{
  font: monospace;
  font-size: 2.778vw;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 3.125rem;
   text-align: right;
   color: white;
   background-color: black;
}

.cancel{
  background-color: #bababa;
  font-size: 2.778vw;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 3.125rem;
   text-align: center;
   border: 1.5px solid black;
}
.cancel:active{
  background: #a0a0a0;
}
.numbers{
  padding: 3.125rem;
  font-size: 2.778vw;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:  #bababa;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}
.numbers:active{
  background: #a0a0a0;
}
.operations{
  padding: 3.125rem;
  font-size: 2.778vw;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:  #ffa642;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}
.operations:active{
  background-color: #ff8905;
}
.zero{
  padding: 3.125rem;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  font-size: 2.778vw;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:   #bababa;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}
.zero:active{
  background: #a0a0a0;
}

.remove-left-border{
  border-left: 0px;
}

.remove-right-border{
  border-right: 0px;
}

.remote-bot-border{
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculatorStyle.css">
    <title>Calculator using JS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-class">
      <center>
      <div class="calculator-begin">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="screen">
           <section>
             XXXXX
           </section>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="cancel remove-left-border">C</button>
          <button class="numbers">←</button>
          <button class="operations remove-right-border">÷</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="numbers remove-left-border">7</button>
          <button class="numbers">8</button>
          <button class="numbers">9</button>
          <button class="operations remove-right-border">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="numbers remove-left-border">4</button>
          <button class="numbers">5</button>
          <button class="numbers">6</button>
          <button class="operations remove-right-border">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="numbers remove-left-border">1</button>
          <button class="numbers">2</button>
          <button class="numbers">3</button>
          <button class="operations remove-right-border">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="zero remove-left-border remove-bottom-border">0</button>
          <button class="operations remove-right-border remove-bottom-border">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want the layout to be rigid and to scale along with the browser size, that is , the relative positions of these elements should remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the horizontal padding from `padding: 3.125rem;` from your CSS. What's happening is that when you shrink your browser, you eventually reach a point where the padding won't allow the container to shrink anymore.

```css
.main-class{
}
.calculator-begin{
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 3.125rem;
  margin-bottom: 3.125rem;
}

.row{
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.screen{
  font: monospace;
  font-size: 2.778vw;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  padding: 3.125rem;
   text-align: right;
   color: white;
   background-color: black;
}

.cancel{
  background-color: #bababa;
  font-size: 2.778vw;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 3.125rem 0;
   text-align: center;
   border: 1.5px solid black;
}
.cancel:active{
  background: #a0a0a0;
}
.numbers{
  padding: 3.125rem 0;
  font-size: 2.778vw;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:  #bababa;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}
.numbers:active{
  background: #a0a0a0;
}
.operations{
  padding: 3.125rem 0;
  font-size: 2.778vw;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:  #ffa642;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}
.operations:active{
  background-color: #ff8905;
}
.zero{
  padding: 3.125rem 0;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  font-size: 2.778vw;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:   #bababa;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}
.zero:active{
  background: #a0a0a0;
}

.remove-left-border{
  border-left: 0px;
}

.remove-right-border{
  border-right: 0px;
}

.remote-bot-border{
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="calculatorStyle.css">
    <title>Calculator using JS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-class">
      <center>
      <div class="calculator-begin">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="screen">
           <section>
             XXXXX
           </section>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="cancel remove-left-border">C</button>
          <button class="numbers">←</button>
          <button class="operations remove-right-border">÷</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="numbers remove-left-border">7</button>
          <button class="numbers">8</button>
          <button class="numbers">9</button>
          <button class="operations remove-right-border">X</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="numbers remove-left-border">4</button>
          <button class="numbers">5</button>
          <button class="numbers">6</button>
          <button class="operations remove-right-border">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="numbers remove-left-border">1</button>
          <button class="numbers">2</button>
          <button class="numbers">3</button>
          <button class="operations remove-right-border">+</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <button class="zero remove-left-border remove-bottom-border">0</button>
          <button class="operations remove-right-border remove-bottom-border">=</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </center>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `padding` you have set on the buttons is making it impossible for the browser to make the elements small enough to fit in the rows. Remove that line and it should work much better. You don't need the padding because your layout is controlled with `flex`.

Comment: Agree with this, but I'd argue only the horizontal padding is necessary to remove for the fix.